# How can I remove the port from the url?

Tags: node.js

I want to hide my port number in NodeJS,
for example:- I was running on a port 4001,if I want to make a request for '/xyz' webhook I need to make a request as 'https://example.com:4001/xyz'  in this I am not interested to show my PORT to others I want to mask or hide it from the public it should be as "https://example.com/xyz"
Please help me to setup as above

Comment: You cant "hide" the port. You can use a webserver like nginx, configure it to listen on standard http(s) ports and forward traffic as reverse proxy to your node app that listens on port 4001. The reason you need to specify the port for your requests is simple that its not a standard http port. Or just use port 80 (if nothing else is allready listening on that port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tldr** switch your nodejs app to run on port 80.

The existing answers are all correct but none explain the why. The HTTP protocol (your site is a http server) uses port 80 as a default, yet you are running your server on port 4001 so it needs to be explicitly stated. If you go to http://example.com you are actually making the http request on port 80, it just doesn't need to be explicitly stated as that is the assumed default. There is no difference between http://example.com:80 and http://example.com.

That being said there is no security need to "mask" or "hide" your port. If you switch it to 80 it isn't hidden it just doesn't need to be typed. The only reason to make this switch is because it is easier, shorter, makes your site look more professional ect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your using localhost to serve your app. Once you deploy to the web, the port number will be handled automatically as all http requests are routed to port 80 by default.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have given port number in your code. just remove that, instead keep `process.env.PORT` or `process.env.PORT || 4001`. so that the server will take port 80 by default.
now you no need to add the port number while visiting the url.